# Scala: how to check whether a object is instance of Array

Tags: scala

I want to check whether a obj in Scala is of type Array, not caring about whether what type of the values are inside. Is there some easy way to do this?

```
var x = Array(1,2,3)
x.isInstanceOf[Array[Any]] // which is false
```

I want it to be true.

**Update:**

I have a function:

```
def someFunction(obj: Any) {
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
        // do something
    }
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[String]) {
        // do something
    }
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Any]) {
        // for each of the obj inside the Array do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**array `Array(1,2,3)` is of type `Int`, so `Array[Any]` would weirdly return false only in case of [`Array` collection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Array.html).**

If you don't care the type of `Array`, you can compare to `Array[_]` (*array of whatever type*)

```
scala> var x = Array(1,2,3)
x: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Array[Int]]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Array[_ <: Any]]
res7: Boolean = true

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Array[_ <: AnyVal]]
res12: Boolean = true

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Array[_]]
res13: Boolean = true
```

[`scala.Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html) extends `AnyVal` which extends `Any` you can explicitly mentions `_ extends AnyVal`.

**But other scala collections like `List[T]` is instance of `List[Any]`**

```
scala> List(1, 2).isInstanceOf[List[Any]]
res30: Boolean = true

scala> Seq(1, 2).isInstanceOf[Seq[Any]]
res33: Boolean = true
```

**Also, `List[T]` is instance of `Seq[Any]`, because `List` extends [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/Seq.html), and `T` extends `Any`**

```
scala> List(1, 2).isInstanceOf[Seq[Any]]
res35: Boolean = true
```

**AND,** for `if else` you can solve with pattern match way,

```
array match {
   case x: Int => println("int") 
   case x: String => "string" 
   case Array[Int] => println("ints")
   case Array[String] => println("strings")
   case _ => println("whatever")
 }
```

Comment: There is a problem with you List example.  It will always return true no matter what type you use for `T` because of erasure.  `List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[List[String]]` returns true.

Comment: You are very right because its matching the erasure, even `List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]]` returns true, but compiler will warn you that `List[Int] cannot also be a List[String]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
x.isInstanceOf[Array[_]]
```

use `_` for container **any type match**. and for `_` it's called **existential type**.

Document:

[Underscore for existential type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447779/underscore-for-existential-type-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you. It works! But I am a little bit confused about the design. It is more intuitive for beginner to use `Any` here  but why we use underscore. I think every beginner will try `Array[Any]` first instead of `Array[_]`

Comment: I'm not sure why it is more intuitive to use `Any`. An `Array[X]` is an `Array[X]`, it is not an `Array[Y]`. An `Array[Int]` is an `Array[Int]`, it is not an `Array[Any]`. `Array[Int]` and `Array[Any]` are two completely different types, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other. `_` is used as a wildcard character all over Scala, why would it be confusing to use it as a wildcard character here?